# Are the threads generated by 2 separate executor services in different threads guaranteed to be different?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Lets say I have 2 different threads running concurrently. Each thread spins up a cached thread pool executor service that spins a bunch more threads. Will each pool have their own distinct set of threads? Or is there a possibility for threads to be shared between them?

Comment: @fge better make that comment an answer. Each has their own pool etc

Comment: It's possible if you pass in a shared `ThreadFactory` that does it on purpose, but... don't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will each pool have their own distinct set of threads? Or is there a possibility for threads to be shared between them?

Each pool has control over its own threads -- when to create new ones, when to destroy them etc. No two `ThreadPool`s will ever "see" one another's threads.

In other words: there is no "giant pool" at the JVM level from which `ExecutorService`s, or `ScheduledExecutorService`s or even `ForkJoinPool`s would pick from. Were it the case, the maintenance cost would be prohibitive...